# Devarda's alloy procedure

Tags: experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, water-treatment

Hello dear I have a small question
I want to do kjeldahl distillation for a 100 mL sample of water after reduction with devarda's alloy to measure the concentration of nitrate nitrogen... I want to know what is the quantity of alloy must be added to 100 mL water?

Answer (score 1):

Take 10 mL of your solution. Add an equal volume of NaOH 1 M. Heat to 100°C and test if the gas has the odor of ammonia. Or check if the gas has a basic reaction by introducing a small and wet indicator paper in the gas getting out of the hot solution (without teaching the glass container). If yes, it means that there is some ammonium salt in the solution. Heat until this gas production has stopped. When this evolution has finished, add 0.1 g Devarda's alloy, and repeat the same test : odor, or reaction of the gas with a small and wet indicator paper. If the gas is basic, it means that the hot solution contained nitrate or nitrite ions.

Comment: The OP is interested in quantitative approach.

Comment: Thanks dear but I am not doing a qualitative test for nitrate I am doing Kjeldahl distillation with devarda's alloy that's what I am asking for the quantity of alloy needed for 100 mL of water and the exact procedure.